# Using Deno to interact through SSH hangs on p.output()

Tags: ssh, deno

I'm looking to create an SSH sub-process and then interact with the server. I'm hung up on a basic step which is to simply wait until the SSH process has connected. I know that this ssh command connects fine because when I run it with `inherit` instead of `piped`, the ssh shell shows up as expected.

If I understand correctly, `p.output()` listens for stdout until it reaches EOF. I'm assuming that when SSH has connected, it streams the stdout, but does not EOF, and so `p.output()` never gets called.

```js
const encoder = new TextEncoder();
const decoder = new TextDecoder();

const p=Deno.run({
     cmd: ["ssh", "root@mywebsite"],
     stdout: "piped",
     stderr: "piped",
     stdin: "piped"
});

const command = (cmd : string) => p.stdin.write(encoder.encode(cmd))
const getOutput = async () => decoder.decode(await p.output())

await p.output() // <----- Hangs here
await command("cd /home/dev/www")
await command("ls -la")
console.log(await getOutput())

await p.status()
console.log("done")
```

Comment: What's your actual objective? Why not just install Deno on the server?

Comment: My objective is to upload files and create symlinks. It requires to see what files are on a remote server, compare them with local files, see the differences, and do some uploading based on user input.

Comment: Can you install Deno on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It hangs because `.output` will resolve once the entire process output has been read, meaning that until `ssh` command has finished, it will not resolve.

Also have in mind that you need to add `\n` at the end of each command, otherwise it'll never be triggered.

```js
await command("cd /home\n");
await command("ls -la\n");
// if you don't finish the ssh session, .output will never resolve
await command("exit\n");
// now it will work correctly
console.log(await getOutput());
```

In any case if you don't want to close the session to read the output of a given command, what you need to do is use `p.stdout.readable` or `p.stdout.read(buf)` instead.

```
for await const(const chunk of p.stdout.readable) {
   // parse chunk and do something
}
```